# How does Presto kill a running query?

Tags: presto

I'm learning Presto, and trying to figure out how does Presto kill a running query. But I'm confuse about the actual process.

I've known that when Presto get a kill request, or it decide to kill a query that cost too much memory, it will call SqlQueryExecution.fail, but this method seems like just change the QueryStateMachine, so how to stop the running thread?

```
@Override
public void fail(Throwable cause)
{
    requireNonNull(cause, "cause is null");

    stateMachine.transitionToFailed(cause);
}
```

I wonder at which step it aborts the running thread

Comment: The state machine has listeners that kick off the process Piotr described below.

Answer (score 1):

Presto execution is managed in `Driver` instances.
A `Driver` may be currently executing or waiting for a thread.
If a `Driver` is waiting for a thread, it gets closed.
In other case, it gets interrupted and closed.

`Driver`s live on workers. Worker gets information that it should finish from the coordinator. This happens for killed queries, but also for queries with `LIMIT` where only part of the data needs to be read.